# Navigator.pushReplacement() not working when coming from a dialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have a method in which I do a push replacement:

```
  _buyAgain() {
    _bloc.buyAgain();
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            _widgetFactory.createCartScreen()));
  }
```

The method above can be called from a normal context or from a dialog context, with the following code:

```
          if (_bloc.shouldShowNonEmptyCartWarning()) {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    content: Text(static.translate(
                        context, 'orderDetail_nonEmptyCartWarning')),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child:
                            Text(static.translate(context, 'app_cancel')),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        child:
                            Text(static.translate(context, 'app_accept')),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _buyAgain();
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                });
          } else {
            _buyAgain();
          }
```

The thing is that if the method is called from within the option in the dialog, the push replacement does not happen. If the _buyAgain() is called in the else block, then works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Navigator.pop(context);
is probably the culprit. You seem to have pushed the replacement and also popped it out of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Navigator.pop(context);` after `_buyAgain();` will pop whatever screen is at the top of the stack.